# Software and Website for event photography

Tags: tethering, event, sharing

A client of mine is going to have the FA cup at an event. They want to take photographs of their customers with the FA cup, record who each photo is of, upload them to a website, and allow the customers to download their photos. No e-commerce or on-site printing.

(They have asked me as a software person, rather than as a photographer, so excuse me if I'm not fully up to speed.)

My guesses is that there is some software package that might work to do this, but a quick google around has found me software such as Darkroom, Chameleon, MiltonStreet, EPS and 5 Second Photo, but none of them seem to be quite on the mark.

I guess an alternative would be to use the tethering software that comes with the camera, change the file or folder name with each visitor, and then concentrate on a simple app to browse named folders online and download the pictures from there (that's something I can probably cope with putting together a simple bespoke solution for the client, or just use a portfolio app)

This seems like I shouldn't be the first person trying to solve this - any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Olympic Journey" exhibition at the Royal Opera House this summer had much the same problem, only with the Olympic torch rather than the FA Cup. As far as I can tell they went for your bespoke solution: a simple PHP website where you could enter your unique code and retrieve your photo. The site is still up, at http://theolympicjourneytorchphoto.com.

As for issuing you with your unique code: there were two staff members on hand, one took the photos, and another wrote your image number on a preprinted card with the URL on it, and handed it to you. I assume they just ran a simple batch rename, where image DSCYYYY.JPG on SD Card XXX becomes image XXXYYYY.JPG, or something along those lines.

Simple but effective, and good for marketing too; they made you fill in a short form to get your photo from the website...

Comment: That's pretty much what they do at Disney World every time my kids posed with a costumed character.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following?

1. [500px](http://500px.com/)
2. [flickr](http://www.flickr.com)

They could be a front to whatever you have, just link to the source.

For software, I'd normally use Lightroom from Adobe, but you could use anything to upload to any of the photo services. Some of them even provide dedicated apps to do so (ie flickr)

Comment: These provide a way of sharing the picture, but I'm not sure these help solve the problem of how to associate the visitor to their own photo.